# how to display message bag object in laravel blade template?

Tags: laravel, session, message, bag

I want to display my errors in **Laravel blade** template. How should i go about it?

```
return view('edit', [
    "id"      => $request->id,
    "data"    => $data,
    "errors"  => $validator->messages(),
    "success" => null,
]);
```

Expected output is

> The mahajan first name may only contain letters.

But This is displayed if i print `$errors`.

```
{
  "mahajan_first_name":["The mahajan first name may only contain letters."],
  "mahajan_middle_name":["The mahajan middle name may only contain letters."],
  "mahajan_last_name":["The mahajan last name may only contain letters."]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest having a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print them in an unordered list like this:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
   <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```

A single error is shown like this:

```
{{ $errors->first('mahajan_first_name') }}
```

To check if an error exists you can do:

```
@if($errors->has('mahajan_first_name'))
 // your code here
@endif
```